# python sqllite list "assignment index out of range"

Tags: python, sqlite, range, variable-assignment

```
cursor = db.con.execute("SELECT id, dosyano, adi, soyadi, tckimlik, cinsiyet, meslek, evtel, ceptel, created, updated  from client")
label = []

s = 0
for row in cursor:
    for i in range(10):
        print(i,s,row[i])
        label.append(i)
        label[i] = []
        label[i].append(s)
        label[i][s] = row[i]

    s = s + 1


data = {'ID' :label[0], 'Dosya Numarası':label[1], 'Ad Soyad':label[2],
        'TC Kimlik':label[3], 'Cinsiyet':label[4], 'Meslek':label[5], 'Ev Tel':label[6],
        'Cep Tel':label[7], 'Oluşturma':label[8], 'Güncelleme':label[9]}
```

The error I get:

```
    label[i][s] = row[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. What is the desired output?

Comment: Did you want to produce a dictionary per result row, perhaps?

Comment: I fail too see your intent. You append a number, then replace it with an empty list to which you append another number. Then you try assigning something to the s-th element of that list containing only one element. Clarify your intents here, and maybe we can help you then. I strongly suggest you read a bit on python lists.

Comment: sample php ? :)
$label = array();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
 for($s=0;$s<10;$s++){
  $label[$s][$i] = "doldur";
 }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($label);
echo "</pre>";